# running sum with case statements by group

Tags: postgresql, sum, boolean, window-functions, cumulative-sum

I want to count running sum,but my code doesn't work, some ideas why?

```
select id, color, time,  (sum(case when question = 1 then 1 else 0 end) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY time rows) + 
 sum(case when suggestion='True' then 1 else 0 end)  OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY time) + 
sum(case when proposal= 'True' then 1 else 0 end)  OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY time)) as s
from table
```

Here is sample data

```
id       color   time   question    suggestion    proposal 
1         pink    14:00    0          True         False
1         red     15:00    0          False        False
1         blue    13:00    0           False       False
2         green   11:00    0          True         False
2         orange  15:00    1           False       False
```

Result:

```
id       color   time      s
1         pink    14:00    1         
1         red     15:00    1         
1         blue    13:00    0           
2         green   11:00    1          
2         orange  15:00    2
```

Comment: Post sample data and expected results to clarify what you want.

Comment: @forpas added data and result

Comment: What is the data type of the columns suggestion and proposal?

Comment: @forpas boolean

Comment: What is the order of the rows for the running sum? Is it just time, or id first and then time?

Comment: Does id matter here since I partition rows by id?

Comment: If you want to partition by id then why the result for orange is 2?

Comment: @forpas 'Cause I miswrote) Edited the result and data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `SUM()` window function only once, if you convert all the boolean expressions to integers:

```
SELECT id, color, time,
       SUM((question = 1)::int + suggestion::int + proposal::int) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY time) s
FROM tablename
ORDER BY id, time;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=da74a780ac9103120cb9a9e42bbc9ed2).